# Tagging of Place in Facebook Open Graph doesn't show the label on the map pin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I was trying to tag a place via Open Graph in a cross platform posting. I have here a code of what i did:

```
$param['access_token'] = '<VALID ACCESS TOKEN>';
$param['place'] = 'https://foursquare.com/v/lifebit-hq/50d09677e4b019c8164dd068';
$facebookClient->api('/me/<APP_NAMESPACE>:<ACTION_TYPE>', 'POST', $param);
```

My expected output would look like this:

[image]

in which the "label" would automatically pop out in the map pin upon posting. But instead I always get this:

[image]

no labels where attached. The label will only show when I hover the mouse onto the pin.

Here's my Custom Open Graph Configuration:

```
Object Type: Daycard (with a custom 'location' GeoPoint Property field)
Action Type: Visit
Attachment Layout: Map
Highlighted Points: daycard:location
```

Here's my Open Graph Meta Tags for tagging of places

```
<meta property="<APP_NAMESPACE>:location:latitude"  content="7.075569"> 
<meta property="<APP_NAMESPACE>:location:longitude" content="125.61214">
```

Any thoughts of what might I have missed?

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently, the open graph map with the label was done because of a special permission from Facebook.

Comment: i have the exact same issue, any news on this?

Comment: @EyalAlsheich Your app should have special permissions/arrangements with Facebook in order to have the pinned label.

Comment: so there is no way to test things out in the sandbox and see how things will look?

Comment: and where or who do i contact to get these special permisions?

Comment: Try asking in the Facebook Community @EyalAlsheich

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? I saw this while searching an answer for your question.

```
<!-- Begin Open Graph metadata --> 
<meta expr:content='&quot;en_US&quot;' property='og:locale'/> <meta     expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/> 
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/> 
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='URL-FOR-IMAGE-YOU-WANT-TO-USE-IF-THERE-IS-NOT-A-THUMBNAIL-PHOTO-IN-THE-  POST' property='og:image'/>
</b:if> 
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
<!-- Still looking for a way to use the post snippet if there's no description -->
</b:if>
<!-- End Open Graph metadata -->
```

[View the entire article](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2013/06/add-facebook-open-graph-tags-to-blogger-for-better-looking-shares-and-likes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the facebook developers section containing resources for the open graph permissions [Visit facebook developers open graph permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/)

Comment: This is not the "permission" that I was referring. hehe I was referring to the permission that was established by Facebook and The mobile app. More like a some kind of partnership.